# Nodejs error while trying to access sharepoint

Tags: node.js, sharepoint

I get the following error while trying to access SharePoint from nodejs

> events.js:71
>           throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                          ^
>   Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>       at errnoException (net.js:769:11)
>       at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:760:19)

below is the code

```
var SP = require('sharepoint'),
site = //url,
username = //username,
password = //password;
var client = new SP.RestService(site),
contacts = client.list('Contacts');
var showResponse = function (err, data) {
console.log(data); 
}
client.signin(username, password, function () {
 // At this point, authentication is complete,
// so we can do requests.



// Example request: Get list items

// showResponse is used as callback function

contacts.get(showResponse)

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The important part of that error message is `ECONNREFUSED`, meaning the connection was refused right away. That means it never got to the point of checking your username and password or anything.

You should double-check your value for `site`. Maybe the server is running on a different port or you have a typo in that value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SharePoint module implementation you've to pass the entire url addressing the REST service.

In SharePoint 2010 the entire REST Service url should look like this

http:// %%SharePointSiteUrl%% /_vti_bin/ListData.svc

You should double check the outgoing requests direction SharePoint by using fiddler or an alternative HTTP watcher.